# How To Use Custom Font In ReportLabs Form TextField

Tags: reportlab

I'm trying to use a different font other than the default 14 in a TextField but keep getting this error

I register the font

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Calibri', 'Calibri.tff'))
```

but when i choose the font in the TextField I get the error

ValueError: form font name, 'Calibri', is not one of the standard 14 fonts

Any idea where I am going wrong please?